# A quantum machine that works unitarily and doesn't produce heat

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

For decades since my physics master's I daydreamed about machines that work on a quantum level unitarily.  The reason I found it interesting was because I knew that unitaries map pure states to pure states and hence don't increase "entropy": $tr( \rho ln(\rho))$.

I have never read up on this, but I did recently.  [I found this article.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0003491615000068). It confirms what I had suspected.  Machines seen this way would defy the second law of thermodynamics.  The authors then go on to define a form of entropy that conforms to the second law for quantum systems evolving under unitary evolution.  I wonder if there is some way that we can make a machine that works carefully on unity evolution of quantum systems to produce what we really want: heatless work.  This is probably related to the stymied efforts of quantum computing engineers to make quantum computers.